# Singleton destructor in Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, singleton, destructor

Once I create a singleton, how do I destruct the code inside it? I have a warning that is presented in the singleton which consumes `StreamController`, and it requires closing. But there is no method in which I can call the `close()` function.

This is the singleton code I have at the moment. `StreamController` is creating the warning I want to fix.

```
class MyService {
  static final MyService _instance = MyService._privateConstructor();

  StreamController<List> _streamController = StreamController<List>.broadcast();

  factory MyService() => _instance;

  MyService._privateConstructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```dart
// Disposable interface
abstract class Disposable {
  void dispose();
}

// Target class
class MyService implements Disposable {
  static final MyService _instance = MyService._privateConstructor();
  StreamController<List> _streamController = StreamController<List>.broadcast();
  factory MyService() => _instance;
  MyService._privateConstructor() {}

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
  }
}

// Example of call
MyService.dispose();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am missing something, but if you have a singleton, what stops you from implementing a `close()` method on the singleton?

Comment: close() is a method that I need to call on a property located in that singleton (StreamController property type). If I don't implement it, I get warning that I need to call it, so I want to get rid of it.

Comment: I see. Any chance you could post your code, or a simple repro so I can see how you have your singletion implemented ?

Comment: I've updated my question above, with the singleton example

Comment: Close instances of `dart.core.Sink`.

Comment: wondering if you are running into this: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35221 (close_sinks rule false positive)